# Open DB Connection within PHP Function

Tags: php, mysql, include, global, whmcs

I wrote an addon module for our WHMCS billing system a long time ago that we recently realized was causing some issues. Essentially each module's PHP file is loaded regardless if it is actually used or not, where this is how their "hook" system is setup.

When I wrote the module, I included my "db_config.php" file at the top in the global space, which I now realize is causing this database to load every page and is apparently being written to when it shouldn't be. As this is the case, I would like to open the Database connection at the top of the function and close it at the end of the function.

I've never seen this done before nor can I find much information on it. The contents of my db_config.php appear as follows and I am wondering if I can just include_once() inside of the function?

```
<?php

// Connection's Parameters
$hostname = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$database = "database";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Connection
$tca_conn = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

if(!$tca_conn)
{
    die('Cannot Establish Connection to Database : ' . mysql_error());
}

$tca_db = mysql_select_db($database, $tca_conn);

if (!$tca_db)
{
    die ('Cannot Select Database : ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.It might work for you.

```
$tca_db = mysql_select_db($database);
```

instead of

```
$tca_db = mysql_select_db($database, $tca_conn);
```

Comment: The problem is that WHMCS already keeps a persistent MYSQL connection to its own database open, why I created the $tca_conn variable to reference this one. In the module, I then call it using $GLOBALS["tca_conn"] but apparently this is not sufficient to keep it separated.

Comment: Instead of "db_config.php", you can create 1 "parameter.ini" file and put all DB related details in it as parameters.Call these parameters in your "main.php" by parsing parameters.